# Global logging service

Tags: php, symfony

I have written my own logging class that I defined as a service and placed inside the `AppBundle\Services` namespace. I can access it easily inside the controller when I want to log something, but what about accessing it from other services?

I'd have to pass the logging service as a dependency injection, but what if I have more than 100 services defined (services, modules, event listeners etc. etc.), each of them having their own dependencies? It would create a mess.

I've been also thinking about extending some core service that defines the  logging service, but then again - all my services, modules, event listeners, would have to extend one core class.

What's the best approach to solve this?

Comment: In services dispatch an event and listen to it with your logger.

Comment: If you already have 100+ services then injecting a logger as needed hardly seems like it would create a mess.  I suppose you could try adding some sort of logging tag to your service definitions then using a compiler pass to actually inject the logger.  But hardly seems worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

May be a good approach would be to rethink responsibilities in order to avoid the creation of too many services.

About the fact of consumming service itself, I think there are no problem to reuse as much as you need along the application lifecycle. In fact, symfony will handle the instantiation and you will be only consumming it as a service.

Another approach will be to create base classes for all your core objects, let these base classes to handle log services and final classes will log in a implicit way.  This will not save service calls but almost will leave you to handle it manually.

If you think you will use your log feature in several projects then I recommend you to move to vendors folder and use it as external module, synchronised via composer to your github account.  It will be like your own 3rd party product.

If you are not a symfony friend then you can break the law and create your own singleton pattern available by autoloading, but I think you should take advantage of the powerfull symfony service structure.